# How to print all input with types and names using jquery on console

Tags: jquery, traversal

I want to print all input within form tag with their types and names using jquery on console.

Comment: Why you need this? Validation???

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** to iterate

```js
$('form input').each(function() {
  console.log('name : ' + this.name + ', type : ' + this.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="a" type="text">
  <input name="b" type="text">
  <input name="c" type="radio">
  <input name="d" type="checkbox">
  <input name="e" type="hidden">
  <input name="f" value=submit type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: i want some clarification Pranva `this.name, this.type` -> vanilla js? `$(this).attr('name') $(this).attr('type')` -> jquery?

Comment: @Pekka , `this` refers to dom object and `name` and `type` is it's property

Comment: if this refers to DOM object `$(this)` _ refers to the DOM object as well right? i am just confused when i saw your answer

Comment: @Pekka : `$(this)` is jQuery object

Comment: I see. I appreciate the explanation Pranav it helped me alot in understanding the difference. Because i have hard time understanding the other answers in the post regarding their difference

Comment: Last question even if i use query selector i can access the DOM object right?